# Create a new user on the xmpp server

Tags: ruby, xmpp

I'm trying to create a new xmpp user from my rails application when a user registers. I did not find an easy way to create a new xmpp user with the xmpp4r (or any other) gem. Do you know how I can manage to create an xmpp user with ruby?

Comment: Try converting http://anandafit.info/2011/05/10/register-new-xmpp-users-with-xmpphp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMPP server that you connect to must allow [in-band registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html). When you are sure that the server allows in-band registration, follow the protocol in [XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) to register an XMPP account at the server.

See section 3.1 in the linked XEP for the simple exchange that is required to achieve this.

You can use either xmpp4r or [blather](http://github.com/adhearson/blather) to send the stanzas and respond to the server's replies. Blather has no built-in support for XEP-0077, but this only means that you'll have to send the stanzas manually.

xmpp4r comes with a `register` method that should do all that for you (see [docs](http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/rdoc/classes/Jabber/Client.html#M000627) here).

Comment: I'm done with this project for a long time, i finally used the openfire api, but your answer is correct so i'll accept it ! Thanks.